# Scala Unable to pimp NaturalTransformation in scalaz or cats

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats, kind-projector

For some reason the following fails to work

```
object NtExtTest {
  implicit class NaturalTransformExt[M[_], N[_]](val self: NaturalTransformation[M,N]) extends AnyVal {
    def test(b:Boolean) = b
  }
 }
```

when I call the method `test` on a natural transform.  Intellij recognises it as an extension function, but the compile gives `value test is not a member of cats.~>` . The same happens when using the scalaz NaturalTransformation.  Is there something I can do to help the compile recognise the extension?

Scala version is 2.11.8

An example which fails:

```
  import NtExtTest._

  class NtTest[B] extends NaturalTransformation[Either[B,?], Xor[B,?]] {
    def apply[A](fa: Either[B, A]): Xor[B, A] = {
      fa match {
        case Left(l) => Xor.left(l)
        case Right(r) => Xor.right(r)
      }
    }
  }

  val test = new NtTest[String]
  test.test(false)
```

(above uses kind projector plugin, but equally fails with type lambdas, or single param higher kinded types)

Comment: What is the actual code that produces that error?

Comment: implicit classes should be inside of another object/trait/class. Try to wrap your `NaturalTransformExt` class in an object (e.g. `Foo`) and say `import Foo._` before calling `test.test(false)` http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html

Comment: @smoes Sorry just assumed that as given, changed code accordingly

Comment: So, what error is produced?

Comment: Value test is not a member of NtTest

Answer (score 0):

Probably relates to [SI-8286](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8286)

```
object NtExtTest {
  // this will work
  implicit class NatTransExt1[E](val t: NaturalTransformation[Either[E, ?], \/[E, ?]]) {
    def test1(b: Boolean): Boolean = false
  }

  // and this will work
  implicit class NatTransExt2[E](val t: NtTest[E]) {
    def test2(b: Boolean): Boolean = false
  }

  // but this will not work, because NaturalTransformation[F, G] and
  // NaturalTransformation[Either[E, ?], \/[E, ?]] of different kind
  implicit class NatTransExt3[F[_], G[_]](val s: NaturalTransformation[F, G]) {
    def test3(b: Boolean): Boolean = false
  }
}
```

I.e. it is not related to `NaturalTransformation`. It does not work in simple case as well:

```
trait SomeType[F[_]]

class SomeConcreteType[A] extends SomeType[Either[A, ?]]

object SomeTypeExt {
  // this will not compile
  implicit class SomeTypeEnrich[F[_]](val t: SomeType[F]) {
    def test1: Boolean = false
  }
  // this will
  implicit class SomeConcreteEnrich[A](val t: SomeType[Either[A, ?]]) {
    def test2: Boolean = true
  }
}
```

If the goal to extend `NtTest`, probably `NatTransExt1` would be best choice if one would like to stay as generic as possible. `NatTransExt2` is ok, if extension really specific to `NtTest`.